# 1D discrete denoising of image by variational method (the length of smoothing term)

Tags: image-processing, mathematical-optimization, noise

As of speaking about this [1D discrete denoising via variational calculus](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejOpmbYM5d0) I would like to know how to manipulate the length of smoothing term as long as it should be `N-1`, while the length of data term is `N`. Here the equation:

```
E=0;
for i=1:n
 E+=(u(i)-f(i))^2 + lambda*(u[i+1]-n[i])
```

- `E` is the cost of actual `u` in optimization process
- `f` is given image (noised)
- `u` is output image (denoised)
- `n` is the length of 1D vector.
- `lambda>=0` is weight of smoothness in optimization process (described around 13 minute in video)

  here the length of second term and first term mismatch. How to resolve this?
  More importantly, I would like to use linear equation system to solve this problem.

Comment: Please add more information. You haven't specified a language, what code do you have so far?

Comment: The question, as it stands, it better suited for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), as it is not specifically related to a programming question.

Comment: what denoising technique you want to implement/referring to (FIR,FFT based, neural network based ,FUZY logic based ...)? What are the input signal properties? What noise you want to get rid of .... Add sample. What are the constraints (runtime,accuracy,memory,...)?  What language/platform ... also I tend to think you will have more luck in http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ with this as such tasks are usually done on DSP ....so you will find much more people with this knowledge there

Comment: @Spektre    
Hi guys, I just want to implement, minute 28 of [link]:(youtube.com/watch?v=ejOpmbYM5d0) in Matlab. I want solve a linear equation system. First i need to write the unknown variables of matrices, then it will be trivial to solve it in matlab by taking the inverse of coefficients and multiply it with known variables(given f) –

Comment: @mexes have edited your question look if I did not broke something especially the `E` is scalar  if you got a vector edit it so text matches your problem (not how I see it)

Comment: @mexes finished editing btw my guts are telling me that `(u[i+1]-n[i])` should be in `abs` or powered by `2` like the first term to avoid messing up the optimization (if you are looking for the `u` when `E` is minimal if this is already derived term (does not look like it) then it will stay as is...

Answer (score 0):

This is nowhere near my cup of tea but I think you are referring to the fact that:

- `u[i+1]-n[i]`  is accessing the next pixel making the term work only on resolution 1 pixel smaller then original `f` image

In graphics and filtering is this usually resolved in 2 ways:

1. **use default value for pixels outside image resolution**

   - you can set default or neutral(for the process) color to those pixels (like black)
   - use color of the closest neighbor inside image resolution
   - interpolate the mising pixels (bilinear,bicubic...)

I think the first choice is not suitable for your denoising technique.

2. **change the resolution of output image**

   Usually after some filtering techniques (via FIR,etc) the result is 1 pixel smaller then the input to resolve the missing data problem. In your case it looks like your resulting `u` image should be 1 pixel bigger then input image `f` while computing cost functions.

   So either enlarge it via bullet **#1** and  when the optimization is done you can crop back to original size.

   Or virtually crop the `f` one pixel down (just say `n'=n-1`) before computing cost function so you avoid access violations (and also you can restore back after the optimization...)